# How do I backup a partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, format

I want to backup a partition of my present harddisk to another hard-disk. If I use Windows Backup, it only offers to backup the system drive. I have a partition/drive which contains some precious data.

I want to backup them on a regular basis on my external hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install [Macrium Reflect free edition](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx), an excellent imaging program which lets you backup any drive/partition you want.

[image]